# Re-write F# code in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, f#

Some time ago, I did some F# programming, the following code is used to serialize/deserialize float32 array:
    #light

However, nowadays, I have to do some programming in VB.NET to serialize/deserialize float32 array again.  As F# programming is not suitable for GUI, but GUI is necessary for my current programming.
I want to know how I can rewrite the above code in VB.NET.
For example, I have a float32 array, (I don’t know what data type in VB.NET is equivalent to float32 array in F#) of (1.0, 2.0, 3.0); I want to serialize it using DataContractSerializer, then read it back so I can still get the same float32 array.
Please share your code.
Thanks and have a nice day!
John

Comment: I don't know where you got that F# wasn't suitable for GUI programming. If you watch some of Don Syme's videos you will see you can build a GUI interactively with FSI and it works pretty well.

Comment: I'll share my code if you share yours :)

Comment: You can also use VB.NET to create your GUI and call your F# functions right from VB.

Answer (score 5):

`float32` is an alias for `System.Single` (see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353708.aspx).

If you can gain value from using the WinForms designer then, yes, I'd agree VB.NET or C# would be the way to go. But did you know that you can reference F# libraries from VB.NET projects? That means you could write your GUI in VB.NET and reuse your F# components without the need for rewrites.

If you are going to hand-code your GUI, then I disagree: F# is perfectly good for writing hand-coded GUIs (indeed, F#'s `async` is excellent for writing non-blocking GUI code).