# Re-write F# code in VB.NET

Tags: f#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Re-write F# code in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6975811/re-write-f-code-in-vb-net)

Some time ago, I did some F# programming, the following code is used to serialize/deserialize float32 array:

```
#light
open System
open System.IO
open System.Runtime.Serialization
open System.Text

let write(x : float32[]) =
    let ds = new DataContractSerializer(typeof<float32[]>) 
    let ms = new MemoryStream()
    ds.WriteObject(ms, x)
    ms.ToArray()

let read(x : byte[]) =
    let ds = new DataContractSerializer(typeof<float32[]>)
    let ms = new MemoryStream(x)
    ds.ReadObject(ms) :?> float32[]

let x = [|1.0f; 2.0f; 3.0f|]
let xb = write(x)
let y = read(xb)
printfn "x = %A" x
printfn "y = %A" x
printfn "Done"
```

However, nowadays, I have to do some programming in VB.NET to serialize/deserialize float32 array again.  As F# programming is not suitable for GUI, but GUI is necessary for my current programming.
I want to know how I can rewrite the above code in VB.NET.
For example, I have a float32 array, (I don’t know what data type in VB.NET is equivalent to float32 array in F#) of (1.0, 2.0, 3.0); I want to serialize it using DataContractSerializer, then read it back so I can still get the same float32 array.
Please share your code.
Thanks and have a nice day!
John

Comment: Please edit the original question (which already has answers) when adding context.  There's no need to open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

More or less this

```
Public Function write(x As [Single]()) As Byte()
    Dim ds = New DataContractSerializer(GetType([Single]()))
    Dim ms As New MemoryStream()
    ds.WriteObject(ms, x)
    Return ms.ToArray()
End Function

Public Function read(x As Byte()) As [Single]()
    Dim ds As New DataContractSerializer(GetType(Singlet32()))
    Dim ms As New MemoryStream(x)
    Return DirectCast(ds.ReadObject(ms), [Single]())
End Function
```

I think You can take it from here?

Comment: Hello:  Thank you very much, your code works.  There is a little typing mistake in Function read:    Public Function read(x As Byte()) As [Single]()
        Dim ds As New DataContractSerializer(GetType(Single()))
        Dim ms As New MemoryStream(x)
        Return DirectCast(ds.ReadObject(ms), [Single]())
    End Function